# Android webview.loadData() does not display tabs

Tags: android, css, webview

I am new to css and android. I am trying to load a gist in a webview but the code's indentation is not coming when i am using `webview.loadData(content, "text/html", "utf-8");` It is working well when i use `webview.loadUrl(url);` but I want the previous. Am I missing something big here? Oh and the indentation is coming in gist by css property `white-space: pre;`. Here is my code:

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.algoView);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webview.loadUrl("https://gist.github.com/tanaykumarbera/c9f7f3e7490a1c002649/" ); // works perfectly

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://gist.github.com/tanaykumarbera/c9f7f3e7490a1c002649", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() { 

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] res) {
            String data="";
                ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(res);
                String response = "";int c;
                while( (c = b.read()) != -1) {
                    response += Character.toString((char) c);
                }
                webview.loadData(response, "text/html", "utf-8"); // Not Working!!
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,  byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshots:

http://postimg.org/image/rjz6e18fv/

http://postimg.org/image/u2kvepu63/

Any ideas on how to load it locally or should I read raw markdown instead would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After fiddling with it for quite a while I found that instead of

```
 webview.loadData(response, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

using

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", response, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

fixes the issue although I have no idea why the css tabs are not working with the previous code.

Comment: If this fixes your issue, you might have some non-URI-escaped character in your HTML. If you still want to use `loadData`, try calling `Uri.encode(response)` on your HTML string before passing it to the web view. According to this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36906575#c23 comment, when using `loadData`, the application is responsible for the URI encoding of the data, whereas when using `loadDataWithBaseURL`, the web view is responsible for encoding the data.